# json jq add same element to each object/array

Tags: json, jq

I have files with json structure like this:

```
[
  {
    "uid": 11111,
    "something": {
        (...)
    }
  },
  {
    "uid": 22222,
    "something": {
        (...)
    }
  }
]
```

I'll read all files at one time (cat *) and i'd like to know which part is from which file, so i need to group it in some way.

So, my idea is to move content of each file to higher (parent) object with own members.

```
[
  {
  "var1": "val1"
  "var2": "val2"
    {
      "uid": 11111,
      "something": {
            (...)
      }
    },
    {
      "uid": 22222,
      "something": {
            (...)
      }
    }
  }
```

How to do that with jq?

Comment: Can you provide a full input and full output example? I have no idea where "var1" and "var2" are supposed to come from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# For simplicity, assume each file in FILELIST contains a single JSON entity.
# Then instead of using cat FILELIST, use mycat FILELIST, e.g. mycat *.json

function mycat {
  for file
  do
    jq --arg file "$file" '{"file": $file, "contents": .}' "$file"
  done
}
```

If you have a sufficiently recent version of jq (e.g. jq 1.5) then one alternative would be:

```
jq '{file: input_filename, contents: .}' FILELIST
```